# Setup App Insights for an application which is hosted on a server with no internet

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Is there a way to setup Application Insights on Azure for an application which is setup on a server with no internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to setup Application Insights for servers with no internet connections.

Because Application Insights sends dc.services.visualstudio.com and f5.services.visualstudio.com with port 80 and 443. Please read below article.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-troubleshoot-faq/